# Can we use similar variable as fixed effects and random effect variable in a linear mixed model?

Tags: lme4, mixed-models

I am doing a study looking looking at the predictors of mortality (binary variable) for a certain procedure. This involves 1000 procedures performed in different centre by different surgeons. I want to use as fixed effects variable in the model the surgeon experience (number of cases per surgeon before index procedure) and hospital volume (number of cases per hospital) becaue I want to assess surgeon and centre experience. I also want to use as random variable (categorical) the surgeon who perfromed the cases and hospital where the case was performed where I expected that there will be nested variation/structure.

Mortality~Variable1 + Variable 2 + Variable 3 (number of cases per surgeon) +  (number of cases per hospital) + (1|surgeon) + (1|centre)

Many thanks

I wanted to understand if there is any bias in using similar variables as random and fixed effects (please note that for fixed my cariable is continous/numerical and for random is categorical).

Comment: This all seems reasonable, but I don't quite understand the question. The example you've given here doesn't include "similar variables as random and fixed effects". (You have surgeon experience and hospital volume as fixed effects, surgeon ID and hospital ID as (intercept) random effects; that seems fine.)